# Parse 940 warehouse X12 in XSLT

Tags: xslt, x12

I wanted to see if there is away to get the N3 and N4 lines of the 940 X12 when the N1 line is the ST (Shipping Address)

Here is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Interchange">
<xsl:apply-templates select="FunctionGroup/Transaction/Loop[@LoopId='0300']/Loop[@LoopId='0310']"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Loop[@LoopId='0310']" >
    <xsl:variable name="order" select="../../."/>
    <xsl:variable name="customer" select="../../Loop[@LoopId='0100']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="line" select="../."/>
    <xsl:variable name="SKU" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/W05/W0502"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/W05/W0503"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/W05/W0504"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N1[N101='ST']/N104"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>    
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N1[N101='ST']/N102"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N3/N301"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N4/N401"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N4/N402"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N4/N403"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$customer/N4/N404"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/G62[G6201='10']/G6202"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/G62[G6201='02']/G6202"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$order/W66/W6605"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$line/LX/LX01"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SKU/W01/W0105"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SKU/W01/W0101"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SKU/W01/W0107"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

sample X12:

ST*940*6470101~
W05*N*14071*display~
N1*BT*Boss Counter Displays~
N3*18 Sandhopper Trail~
N4*Westpart*CN*06881~
N1*ST*Sam Malone*91*BD01~
N3*17 Sandhopper Trail~
N4*Westport*CT*06880*US~
N9*23*Boss Counter Displays~
G62*10*20190311~
G62*02*20190312~
W66*CC*M***UPE~

Thank you!

Comment: Please update your post to explain what your specific issue is: you say what you're trying to accomplish, but you don't say what trouble you're having.  Please also include a sample of your input XML, and your desired output XML.  Ideally, we'll be able to help you best if you provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In addition, the XPath expressions in your sample XSLT have no apparent relevance to anything...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the right occurrence.

Just needed the [2] to get the second occurrence of the N3 record in the loop.